# Bluemix API management service APIs

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I am looking for Bluemix API management apis to move apis through different environments as a part of devops process. I also want to setup same set of APIs for multiple tenants where each API proxy to a different backend. I could not find any such APIs documented.

Any workarounds, approaches or suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

API Connect (new version of API Management) which is also available on Bluemix includes a new Toolkit focused in scenarios for DevOps. Here it is its documentation and APIs: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/rapim_cli_command_summary.html?lang=en